# Display product discount above regular price in order summary on checkout in WooCommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I want to display product discount above regular price in order summary and checkout.

I'm using "[WooCommerce: Display Product Discount in Order Summary @ Checkout](https://www.techiesandesh.com/woocommerce-display-product-discount-order-summary-checkout-cart/)". But this shows on the left (before the regular price).

I want it to show up on top. So I want to show the discount above the regular price.

```php
/**
 * @snippet       WooCommerce: Display Product Discount in Order Summary @ Checkout, Cart
 * @author        Sandesh Jangam
 * @donate $7     https://www.paypal.me/SandeshJangam/7
 */
  
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_subtotal', 'ts_show_product_discount_order_summary', 10, 3 );
 
function ts_show_product_discount_order_summary( $total, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
     
    //Get product object
    $_product = $cart_item['data'];
     
    //Check if sale price is not empty
    if( '' !== $_product->get_sale_price() ) {
         
        //Get regular price of all quantities
        $regular_price = $_product->get_regular_price() * $cart_item['quantity'];
         
        //Prepend the crossed out regular price to actual price
        $total = '<span style="text-decoration: line-through; opacity: 0.5; padding-right: 5px;">' . wc_price( $regular_price ) . '</span>' . $total;
    }
     
    // Return the html
    return $total;
}
```

Comment: This is a matter of adding CSS, display block versus inline

Comment: Thank you. So, how can i do it ?

Comment: Show me your page link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this code

```
 //Prepend the crossed out regular price to actual price
 $total = '<span style="text-decoration: line-through; opacity: 0.5; padding-right: 5px;">' . wc_price( $regular_price ) . '</span>' . $total;
```

Instead of prepending, append the value to the total. Replace the above code with this code.

```
 //Append the crossed out regular price to actual price
 $total = $total . '<span style="text-decoration: line-through; opacity: 0.5; padding-right: 5px;">' . wc_price( $regular_price ) . '</span>';
```

If you want to show it above the price then change `span` to `div` or use `display:block;` to `span` style.

Comment: Unfortunately, this time the crossed out discount is on the right. The one I discount; I want on the regular one.
The discounted one will be above.